# Subtraction of single precision IEEE 754 numbers

Tags: math, binary, ieee-754, arithmetic-expressions

The problem is (-1.100 x 2^5) + (1.1001 x 2^7).
After shifting to get them both to the same magnitude you would get

```
 1.10010 x 2^7
-0.01100 x 2^7
```

My problem is with carrying. I'm not sure if I am doing it right.
The answer I got was 0.01110 x 2^7, is this correct? Also, when subtracting how do I know if I would end up with a negative value? If the answer I have above is correct, would the correct representation in single precision IEEE be

`0 10000110 011100000000000000000000`

Comment: No. Posting your code would help us figure out what's going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Check your work by adding the difference (the result) to the subtrahend (the number after the minus sign). If you get the minuend (the number before the minus sign), you did it correctly.

```
    11      // the carries from the addition
  0.01100   // the difference you computed
+ 0.01110   // the subtrahend
---------
  0.11010   // should be the minuend, if you computed the difference correctly
```

That is not the minuend (1.10010), so you subtracted incorrectly.

Comment: Ok that makes sense for if i want to check my work, but how would i keep track of the borrowing in order to do the subtraction correctly.